# How to import all data form a kanban board to scrum board in two projects

Tags: project-management, jira, agile, scrum, kanban

I am using jira. I have a kanban project called **`kanban_new`**. The board for the project is **`kanban_new_board`**

I have an empty scrum board called **`scrum_new`**. I want to copy all data of **`kanban_new_board`**  to **`scrum_new`**. Is that possible?

I tried to create a new board from existing project, i.e. **`kanban_new`**. By doing so i have now two boards of the same project:

**`kanban_new_board`  and `scrum_new` .**

I want to have only one board for the project

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boards are better thought of as views on to project data, they don't have much data themselves.

You don't **copy** anything from one board to another. You create a new board and tell it to use a filter that returns the same issue list as the other board. Then delete the board you don't want.